# SQLAlchemy: Multiple ForeignKeyConstraint referencing the same destination Column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to properly define the relations between a few tables that all use composite keys. The issue I am facing is that one Column used in those keys is common to all the tables.

Consider the following tables and relations, written using sqlalchemy:

```
class Match(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'match'
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    players = relationship('PlayerMatch', back_populates='match')
    region = Column(String, primary_key=True, nullable=False)

class Player(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'player'
    id = Column(String, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    matches = relationship('PlayerMatch', back_populates='player')
    region = Column(String, primary_key=True, nullable=False)

class PlayerMatch(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'player_match'
    match = relationship('Match', back_populates='players')
    match_id = Column(String, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    player = relationship('Player', back_populates='matches')
    player_id = Column(String, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    region = Column(String, primary_key=True, nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(['region', 'player_id'], ['player.region', 'player.id']),
        ForeignKeyConstraint(['region', 'match_id'], ['match.region', 'match.id']),
    )
```

This is obviously conflictual for sqlachemy since it doesn't know how to fill the `region` attribute of `PlayerMatch`. It throws the following warning:

`SAWarning: relationship 'PlayerMatch.match' will copy column match.region to column player_match.region, which conflicts with relationship(s): 'PlayerMatch.match' (copies player.region to player_match.region). Consider applying viewonly=True to read-only relationships, or provide a primaryjoin condition marking writable columns with the foreign() annotation.`

Note that `region` is guaranteed to be the same for both the match and player involved in this relation. As is, it still works but gives me the previous warning. I've spent some time trying to define join conditions of the various relationships but I can't get it to work properly. I'd be fine with a mechanism to simply indicate which `region` (coming from `Match` or from `Player`) is to actually be persisted in `PlayerMatch`.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/join_conditions.html#overlapping-foreign-keys

Comment: I had seen this but did not understand it fully. I went back to it thanks to your comment and understood what I was missing, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to specify the `primaryjoin` attribute of the `PlayerMatch.player` relationship in order for it to use both `Player.id` and `Player.region`, but to prevent from persisting the `region` coming from `Player`, as follows:

```
player = relationship(
        'Player',
        back_populates='matches',
        primaryjoin="and_(Player.id == foreign(PlayerMatch.player_id), "
                    "Player.region == PlayerMatch.region)"
    )
```