# SQLAlchemy many-to-many relationship with SHARED composite keys

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I created a SQLAlchemy many-to-many relationship with composite primary-keys. Therefore also the foreign keys between the three tables are composite. One of the primary-key columns is shared. It has to be of the same value.
[image: Diagram of the three tables]
The code I used seems to work, however I do now get warnings that say: *relationship 'A.bs' will copy column B.group to column A_B.group, which conflicts with relationship(s): 'A.bs' (copies A.b to A_B.group). Consider applying viewonly=True to read-only relationships, or provide a primaryjoin condition marking writable columns with the foreign() annotation.*

```
class A(Model):
  group = Column(Int, primary_key=True)
  id = Column(Int, primary_key=True)
  bs = relationship('B', secondary=Table('A_B',
    Column('group', Int, primary_key=True),
    Column('a', Int, primary_key=True),
    Column('b', Int, primary_key=True),
    ForeignKeyConstraint(['group', 'a'], ['A.group', 'A.id']),
    ForeignKeyConstraint(['group', 'b'], ['B.group', 'B.id'])
  ))

class B(Model):
  group = Column(Int, primary_key=True)
  id = Column(Int, primary_key=True)
```

I cannot set the relationship to viewonly. How do I have to modify my code to make it work without the warning?

Comment: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/join_conditions.html#overlapping-foreign-keys

Comment: So it is not possible to resolve the warning and still use the "secondary" argument? The "duplicate"-solution uses an additional table which has problems.

Comment: I don't see why you couldn't use a secondary, you just have to inform SQLA what it can modify or not based on a relationship, and passing an explicit `primaryjoin` and `secondaryjoin` with annotations is a way to do that. Maybe this is different enough from the one-to-many case that the duplicate doesn't quite cover it clearly enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to [providing the `primaryjoin`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59631645/sqlalchemy-multiple-foreignkeyconstraint-referencing-the-same-destination-colum) with annotations like in the error message, you have to provide the `secondaryjoin` when making a many to many relationship through a secondary table:

```
a_b = Table('A_B',
  Column('group', Integer, primary_key=True),
  Column('a', Integer, primary_key=True),
  Column('b', Integer, primary_key=True),
  ForeignKeyConstraint(['group', 'a'], ['a.group', 'a.id']),
  ForeignKeyConstraint(['group', 'b'], ['b.group', 'b.id'])
)

class A(Model):
  group = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  bs = relationship(
    'B', secondary=a_b,
    primaryjoin='and_(A.group == foreign(A_B.c.group), A.id == foreign(A_B.c.a))',
    secondaryjoin='and_(B.group == A_B.c.group, B.id == foreign(A_B.c.b))')

class B(Model):
  group = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

The `A_B.c.group` is not annotated as [`foreign()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.foreign) in the secondary join, so SQLAlchemy does not copy it twice. The downside of that is that it is possible to do unexpected things such as:

```
In [4]: a1 = A(group=1, id=1)

In [5]: a2 = A(group=2, id=1)

In [6]: session.add_all([a1, a2])

In [7]: b_oops = B(group=1, id=2)

In [8]: session.add(b_oops)

In [9]: a1.bs = [B(group=1, id=1), B(group=2, id=2)]

In [10]: session.commit()

In [11]: b_oops in a1.bs
Out[11]: True
```

So `B(group=2, id=2)` is inserted to the database, but `b_oops` gets associated with `a1` instead.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the code. I guess this solution is also not really a good option with these unexpected things happening. There should be an error when trying to append an element with the wrong group.

Comment: It might be doable with a [validator](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/mapped_attributes.html#simple-validators) / events.